# How to fetch only requested file to the linked entity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, multipartform-data

i have list of files in directory which is linked to folder entities in my application,
every file is tied to a unique folder class and has the same reference than the folder id ==> folder.id = file.name
No file entity, When i try to display my folder content, it's fetch all the directory files and not only the one linked to my folder
her's my service display folder content

```
@RequestMapping("/displayfolder")
    public String displayfolder(Model model, String  reffolder, String filename,
            @RequestParam(name="page", defaultValue="0") int page,
            @RequestParam(name="size", defaultValue="10") int size){
        model.addAttribute("reffolder", reffolder);
        model.addAttribute("filename", filename);
        
    try{    
        Folder folder = folderprocess.displayfolder(reffolder);
        model.addAttribute("folder", folder);
        
        model.addAttribute("files", storageService.loadAll().map(
                path -> ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                        .path("/Files/")
                        .path(path.getFileName().toString())
                        .toUriString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
                
    }catch (Exception e) {
        model.addAttribute("error", e);
        return "redirect:/displayfolder?reffolder="+reffolder+
                "&error="+e.getMessage();
    }
        return "edit_folder";
    }
```

loadAll() service:

```
public Stream<Path> loadAll() {
        try {
            return Files.walk(this.rootLocation, 1)
                    .filter(path -> !path.equals(this.rootLocation))
                    .map(this.rootLocation::relativize);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new StorageException("Failed to read stored files", e);
        }

    }
```

How can i fetch only the file linked to the requested folder ?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you explain some more what you tried and what is not working?

Comment: Thks for reply, my application manage multiple folder entities, every folder entity has a document attached and stored in linux OS. files names are same than folder id and are called in folder by the url like : linuxserver:8081/filename, so my problem is how to load the file by name beacause in my case where i use the code below, it's load all file in disk and not only the one needed

Comment: Have you debugged what `loadAll` returns? Is your `filter` and `map` working as intended?